# Indexing Error: I am getting an error that I can't resolve

Tags: indexing

I am using SEO Press Pro for my company's website. When submiting URLs to Google for indexing, I am, getting the following error message: "401 - Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project%22).

I am wondering what the best approach to resolve is this.

Thanks in advance, John

I basically just Google this and found several different ways to resolve this issue. Instead of trying each one, I was wondering if there is any best approach.

Comment: The provided link does not work. Also, please provide more details to your question. What is the exact issue and what do you need support for?